# How to get the text of H1 tag and copy it to another part of the code with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I am in the process of adding "See more" sections to the bottom of some of my web pages. My plan to is to have something like this:

```
<h1 id="test">Unique title</h1>

<h2>See more</h2>
<ul>
<li><a class="link" href="/people/YYYY/category1/">More1</a></li>
<li><a class="link" href="/people/YYYY/category2/">More2</a></li>
<li><a class="link" href="/people/YYYY/category3/">More3</a></li>
<li><a class="link" href="/people/YYYY/category4/">More4</a></li>
<ul>

<script>
let text = document.getElementById("link").innerHTML; 
document.getElementByClass("link").innerHTML = text.replace("YYYY", "test");
</script>
```

I have tried the above script but to no avail.

I have many hundreds of these to do so what I'm looking to do is use Javascript to copy the text in the H1 tag and replace 'YYYY' in the url with that text within the same page.

I have very limited knowledge of Javascript, I tend to only use WS3 snippets, but I'm struggling to find something for what I need.

Please note: there is more code between the H1 and H2 tags, I just haven't included it. Also, the urls in the ul are examples only.

Comment: Why not use your back end code to provide the url dynamically? For example you can set wordpress/php to get the url you want.

Comment: Please edit your question and add in the JS code segment that demonstrates your best attempt at resolving this yourself, and then explain in what part of your code you aren't getting the result you expect.  You should be able to find lots of examples for how to modify the `href` attribute

Comment: There is no `getElementByClass` method You have no element with an id of `link`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an answer to what you are asking, but it is probably not the right way to do what you are trying to do. You probably want to use some sort of back-end code, or a build system.

To get the text content of a tag, you should first add an `id` attribute to it, to make it easy to target with Javascript:

```html
<h2 id="foo">Blah Blah</h2>
```

Then you can easily get a reference that tag with Javascript, and then use the `innerText` property to get the text.

```js
var text = document.getElementById('foo').innerText
```

To replace the text of several href attributes is more tricky. You can first get a reference to them, I suggest using an id attribute on the `<ul>` tag to make this easier:

```html
<ul id="special-links">
```

Then you can use `querySelectorAll` to find the tags:

```js
var aTags = document.querySelectorAll('#special-links a')
```

Then loop through those using `forEach`. For each iteration of the loop, use `getAttribute` to get the href attribute, then use `replace` to replace the YYYY portion with the `text` value we got previously, then use `setAttribute` to set that new string as the new href.

```js
aTags.forEach((tag) => {
    let href = tag.getAttribute('href')
    let newHref = href.replace('YYYY', text)
    tag.setAttribute('href', newHref)
})
```

Comment: I've just tried this out and it works exactly how I wanted it to. This will save me a lot of time. Many thanks, Nathan, much appreciated!